# Regex that can extract a username and password from a postgresql connection string?

Tags: regex

How can I improve this [regex](https://regexr.com/5iiak) `(?<=\/\/)(.*?)(?=\@)` to extract the username:password from a postgresql connection string.

I want to extract this string `db-admin-username@server:this-is-funny-passowrd/is-continuing=` from this string `postgresql://db-admin-username@server:this-is-funny-passowrd/is-continuing=@127.0.0.1/dbname`

It returns the wrong string in case the password or username contains `@`

It should extract anything between `//` and the last `@` characters.

Comment: Did you try `substring('postgresql://db-admin-username@server:this-is-funny-passowrd/is-continuing=@127.0.0.1/dbname' from '//(.*)@')`?

Comment: Or `SELECT regexp_matches(col, '//(.*)@')`

Comment: Thank you! @WiktorStribiżew, using this regex  ` '//(.*)@'` returns the required string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
//(.*)@
```

In Python, you can use

```py
re.findall(r'//(.*)@', text)
```

The `.*` will match from the leftmost `//` till the rightmost `@`, thus returning all the string you need.

Comment: I wasn't particularly selecting from a database but the regex `'//(.*)@'` finds a match in a  string.

Comment: @N.Solomon So, what should I keep in the answer? If it works for you as is please consider accepting the answer. Else, let me know what to fix.

Comment: I only needed the regex `//(.*)@` All I had to do in python is `matches = re.findall(r'\/\/(.*)@',conn_string)`  or in Js ` connString.match(/\/\/(.*)@/g);`